# How to select desired months in rdd based operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, bigdata, rdd

I have an rdd like this,

```
rdd  = sc.parallelize([u'2011-12-29 00:00:00', u'2012-11-29 01:20:00', u'2013-10-29 00:00:00', u'2012-10-29 00:00:00'])
```

I am trying to select the months of `10` & `12`. meaning,

```
2013-10-29 00:00:00
2012-10-29 00:00:00
2011-12-29 00:00:00
```

could anyone tell me how to do it only using rdd based operation?

Comment: try: `rdd.filter(lambda x: x.split('-')[1] in ['10','12']).collect()`

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? Also, have you looked at the docs? Where is your attempt? This might be off-topic.

Comment: @Alexander Cécile.. strange!! I dont know why you say this is off-topic. Yes I did the research!!

Comment: @Mass17 I say it might be off-topic because Stack Overflow is meant for **specific** technical problems. Questions that are simply "How can I" are very often too broad/vague.